# return statement does not work in javascript try block

Tags: javascript, return, try-catch

return statement normally terminate function execution. But I have been realized that return statement does not work like what I expected? Where is the problem?

```
function SimpleSymbols() {
    ["a", "b", "c", "d"].forEach(function (char, index) {
        try {
            console.log("alert");
            return "false";  //this line does not work?
        } catch (err) {

        }
    });
}

SimpleSymbols();
```

Comment: It returns from the `forEach` iteration callback, is that not what you wanted?

Comment: It does work in a `try` / `catch` but not in a `forEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach()` does not return. You can return from outside of the loop once the loop is completed:

```js
function SimpleSymbols() { 
  var r;
  ["a", "b", "c", "d"].forEach(function (char, index) {
    try {
        console.log("alert");
        r = "false";  //this line does not work?
    } catch (err) {
    }
  });
  return r
}

console.log(SimpleSymbols());
```

Instead you can use normal *for* loop:

```js
function SimpleSymbols() { 
  var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    try {
        console.log("alert");
        return "false";  //this line does not work?
    } catch (err) {
    }
  }
}

console.log(SimpleSymbols());
```

Comment: Thank you. You are totally right. I couldn't used to write callback functions yet.